# Child doesn't properly move with the parent

Tags: animation

Apparently, Blender keep anything easier, hard. Like the object is parented at Arrow Axis, when i add key frame and move the frame. Every time I try to move the parent [The Axis] the child [Cell Fractured Plane] doesn't move properly https://youtu.be/T-LzlBQi1mw

Comment: Hello maybe your plane object has a Child Of constraint, which would cumulate with the child relation? But maybe share your file?

Comment: as you can see, you have checked "proportional editing on", just uncheck, and it works as expected. Learning comes before complaining....

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.